# Add OpenGL to Linux Vscode

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio-code, opengl

I followed [this](https://medium.com/geekculture/a-beginners-guide-to-setup-opengl-in-linux-debian-2bfe02ccd1e) tutorial successfully. But it doesn't explain how to configure on vscode. Glad is in this folder `/usr/include` and I did use sudo in the terminal to compile and generate `a.out`. How do I do that in vscode? I have this error output when I try to build task:

### terminal

```
Starting build...
/usr/bin/g++ -fdiagnostics-color=always -g /home/raijin/Documents/Code/C++/OpenGL/*.cpp -I/home/raijin/Documents/Code/C++/OpenGL/ -o /home/raijin/Documents/Code/C++/OpenGL/main
/home/raijin/Documents/Code/C++/OpenGL/main.cpp:3:10: fatal error: /usr/include/glad/glad.h: Permission denied
    3 | #include <glad/glad.h>
```

My tasks is configured like that:

### tasks.json

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++ build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/g++",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${workspaceFolder}/*.cpp",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
                
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "compiler: /usr/bin/g++"
        }
    ]
}
```

How do I configure OpenGL vscode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone has the same problem I solved it adding these args in tasks.json

```
"${workspaceFolder}/*.c",
"-lGL",
"-lglfw",
"-ldl"
```

And the folder `glad` in `/usr/include` for some reason had a gray x on the folder icon and it couldn't be accessed without `sudo` command. I deleted and made a `glad` empty folder and copied `glad.h` inside it. After that the code worked as expected in vscode.